# Poisson bracket vs. bivector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, poisson-geometry

Given a Poisson bracket $\{\cdot,\cdot\}:C^{\infty}(M)\times C^{\infty}(M)\to C^{\infty}(M)$, it is well known that there is a correspondence between this bracket and bivector fields $\pi\in\mathfrak{X}^2(M)$ satisfying $[\pi,\pi]=0$ (this is the Schouten bracket). However, I understand that this correspondence is not "complete", because maybe there are $1-$forms $\alpha,\beta\in T^*M$ such that $\pi(\alpha,\beta)$ is well defined, but if these $1-$forms are not exact, we can't find two functions $f,g\in C^\infty(M)$ such that $\{f,g\}\equiv\pi(\alpha,\beta)$. So, there are elements in $T^*M$ (the domain of $\pi$) that do not correspond to any element in $C^\infty(M)$ (the domain of $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$). Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean bivector *fields*?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, thanks, I'm always making these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: Why would you want to find two functions such that that equation would be true, for arbitrary $1$-forms? That is unnecessary for the correspondence between the two.

Comment: @QuaereVerum, maybe I should rewrite the question, but I mean that the bivector $\pi$ should be considered an "extension" of the bracket, not just equivalent, because in the domain of $\pi$ there will be some elements (non exact $1-$forms) that do not correspond to any elements of $C^\infty( M)$, the domain of $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the Poisson bivector can act on "new", objects, but that does not mean that Poisson bivectors "extend" Poisson brackets in any meaningful way. $\pi:\mathfrak{X}^*M\times\mathfrak{X}^*M\to C^\infty M$ is fully determined by its action on exact forms due to $C^\infty M$-linearity, so, given a bracket, it requires no new information to specify the corresponding bivector.

Comment: Oh, I see. For example, for any $x\in M$ and any $\alpha,\beta\in T_x^*M$ given by $\alpha=f_1(x)dx_1|_x+f_2(x)dx_2|_x$ and $\beta=g_1(x)dx_1|_x+g_2(x)dx_2|_x$ (I'm assuming $\text{dim}(M)=2$), we have $$\pi_x(\alpha,\beta)=(f_1(x)g_2(x)-f_2(x)g_1(x))\cdot \pi_x(dx_1|_x,dx_2|_x), $$ but $dx_1|_x,dx_2|_x$ are exact, even if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not. Is this correct?

Comment: @Yester More or less. Put more simply, exact forms generate the entire $C^\infty M$-module $\mathfrak{X}^*M$.